# How to input a list into my model and not have it care about order

Tags: machine-learning, data, theory

I'm trying to predict a list of numbers, e.g:

```
[23,55,198,200,64]
```

The data I have includes multiple things, along with: 
The numbers from the previous run (These numbers come from scientific experiments) 
A list of all previous lists of numbers 
So for example if two runs ago we got `[22,24,77,187,21]`, 
and the run after that we got `[90,22,76,88,29]`, 
we would now have a list of

`[[22,24,77,187,21],[90,22,76,88,29]]`

The important thing is that it doesn't matter what order the numbers are in. 
`[22,24,77,187,21]` and `[77,22,187,24,21]` are both the same thing.

How do I go about feeding my model this data, in a way that it realizes that both options are correct?

Comment: U can predict individual elements of the sequence and not the entire sequence … but if u feed as a sequence then the order matters and a lot of research is focused on relative and absolute positions for sequence-to-sequence learning …

Answer (score 2):

If the range of possible integers is small, encode the presence of each integer as a boolean column in a feature vector.

Example with a value range of 0-5.

`[1,3,4], [4,3,1], [3,1,4]` would all be encoded as `[0,1,0,1,1,0]`

Comment: This is probably closest to the answer I was looking for.
The one problem with this is that I can't find a way to store all of the previous combinations and allow the model to use them.

Answer (score 1):

Having a series of numbers, in which the order doesn't matter from a scientific point of view, does not necessarily make them easily comparable from a programming point of view.

A simple way to compare them is to sort them systematically first (maybe in a separated array if you need to keep the initial data), even if their order does not matter.